# Почему аватары некоторых пользователей имеют тень?

Tags: поддержка, дизайн, stackexchange

Господа, не могли бы вы объяснить по какому принципу у некоторых пользователей появляется тень по аватаром?

Никакой закономерности я так и не нашёл. Карма уж точно не влияет на это напрямую. Также как и количество заработанных значков, стаж регистрации на сайте и т. д.

Пример:

[image: Пользователь с тенью под аватаром]

Я не являюсь участником «Stack Overflow на русском», но задать этот вопрос мне удобнее именно здесь, среди русскоязычной аудитории.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тень показывается при наличии у пользователя Expanded Usercard - ее видно при наличии у пользователя привилегии [Постоянный Пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) - 750 репутации на бете, 1000 на полноценном сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Развернутая карточка появляется, только если раздел вашего профиля «Обо мне» содержит не менее 28 символов. Если профиль достаточно заполнен, ваша аватарка будет «отбрасывать тень».